# Any workaround Exchange 2003 with Outlook 2013?

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2013

Some customers need to get exchange 2003 working with Outlook 2013 (while MS does not support products after 10 years) (and the customers will not spend more money to upgrade).
is there any workaround to get these 2 beasts work together?

Comment: outlook 2013 is not compatible with exchange server 2003

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is a little complicated, so bear with me.

First, your customer opens an account with a stock broker. Then he starty buying Microsoft stock. Lots of it.

Once he reaches 5% of the company, he can then ask for a seat on the board and raise the issue - he should be prepared to make a takeover offer to buy Microsoft if them are not cooperative.

This is A solution. Not a workable one, but a workaround.

Seriously, customer should pay money or downgrade office.